# vb/aspx single-page model: how to implement server-side captcha while also post form data to another page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, post, web, captcha

I'm using [WebCaptcha](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8751/A-CAPTCHA-Server-Control-for-ASP-NET) However I cannot figure out how to do the POST to verify user captcha input and then in-the-same-post-pipeline also submit the form data to a different webpage only if captcha is correct. I know this is hard w/o full code but...yeah. Here is the button that fires the form:

```
<form runat="server" name="PDFfrm1" id="PDFfrm1" method="post" enableviewstate="false" action=""><!-- action="/Processor.aspx" -->
```

Empty `action=` posts page back to itself.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text=" Submit " Style="border-radius:8px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="" Width="6em" Height="3em" Borderstyle="Groove" Borderwidth="2" Font-Bold="true" BackColor="Navy" ForeColor="White" />
```

The `UseSubmitBehavior=` toggles the button between a normal button and a submit button. Note that Microsoft stuffs a Javascript `__DoPostBack()` function in the `OnClientClick=` section that you can block by adding "//" to that attribute.
Then:

```
Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
If Page.IsValid Then
lblResult1.Text = "CAPTCHA verification passed, your request has been sent!"
Else
lblResult1.Text = "Sorry, the CAPTCHA text was not entered properly, try again."
End If
End Sub
```

I was thinking I would have to add code to the `Page.IsValid` section that does a server-side (ajax??) post to the other webpage because in order for the `btnSubmit_Click()` to get control, the current page has *already* done a post to itself and I don't know how to interrupt that pipeline. I cannot just do a Javascript POST then since the client is not in control at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple: do `Server.Transfer(URL, True)` which preserves the existing session data from within the successful `Page.IsValid` test, allowing the destination page to read the form data as if it had done the POST.